# How to manage access to static content?

Tags: php, static

I need the best way to manage and serve static content such as images, videos, etc.

I need to allow only permitted users to load a particular image or video.

Let's say that I have a dedicated server to serve my PHP application `http://server1.com`
and a dedicated server to serve static content `http://server2.com/image.jpg`
how can I allow or deny a user from accessing that image?

Comment: Could be by referer, by using sessions, by IP... You'd have to be more specific on what you're trying to do. Search the web, there is a lot of documentation.

Comment: How can you check the user's session in a link as this : www.site.com/image.jpg  ??

Comment: You can configure your web server to handle .jpg files as PHP scripts and then serve the image dynamically. Or you can even have something like example.com/image or example.com/image.php. Images don't need to have image file extensions.